# Django: Having problems saving value of datetime.date as null in database

Tags: django, python-2.7, datetime, django-models, django-views

My form looks like this:

[image]

If the 'In Progress' box is checked I want the 'End Date' to be null in the MySQL db when I save the form.

In my model I have this to allow a value of null to be saved (I think?):

`end_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date, blank=True, null=True)`

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but then in my views.py I have this line:

```
if request.POST.get('end_year') == '- Year -':
    end_date = datetime.date(None, None, None)
```

(I would also have similar checks for the Month and Day)

But when I try to submit my form I get 'an integer is required' exception.

As some additional information, when I manually try to change end_date to null in the db I get this error: `Incorrect date value: 'null' for column 'end_date' at row 1`

I'm not really sure what the best way to approach this is. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In python there's no `null` so it doesn't know it should map that to `None`, which the django ORM knows to treat as db null when generating sql. Try sending an empty value from your html/js.

Comment: Where do you get that error? Post whole error with traceback please.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that if you delete the `default` from your `end_date` field, you are going to be ok.

```
end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And now, if it is In progress on your form, then just do not provide any data to `end_date` field. I want to say that you should NOT do this.

```
end_date = datetime.date(None, None, None)
```

But since there is no mode `default` for this field, when it is not In progress, just provide initial data to it from the view or form.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check for following:

1. `end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)`
2. while updating end_date field as NULL just query like `end_date = None` rather than doing `end_date = datetime.date(None, None, None)`.